# Paging UIImages with previews

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimage

How can you set up a `UIScrollView` to be paged and show `UIImages` such as the way app screenshots are presented in the app store (example in the image below).

Having the preview either side for the next / previous image is required too (like the old style tabs in Safari (iPhone) for iOS 6 and below).

I have found some example projects, but nothing I have found seems to work properly.

Does anyone know how to replicate this kind of functionality? I preferably do not want to use third party controls, but I am open to suggestions.

[image: App store app screenshots]

Comment: do you need total screen to be same to the images functionality is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the `UIImageView` frame accordingly so that your screen can show one full image and half of next UIImage. Count the number of images you have and accordingly set the content view of your `UIScrollView`. You can refer this link [Paging-enabled UIScrollView With Previews](http://blog.proculo.de/archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html)
and https://github.com/kejinlu/PagedFlowView

Answer (score 2):

Using UIScrollview and UIImageview inside scrollview You can achieve this,
Count your images  or store them it in array, go through loop and set imageview frame accordning to it.

After counting set **contentSize** of Your scrollview , and enabled Paging of scrollview.

You can do it using this, but still there are so many custom classes for these you can integrate them easily.

Check below **if you want**

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hgpagescrollview
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uiphotogallery
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/infinitescrollview
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dmpagingscrollview
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/apextendedpagecontroller